# Ardunio wireless voice transmission

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-nano, bluetooth, wireless

I made a project based on calling with gsm module and arduino and  now i want to transmit to voice wirelessly to my bluetooth earphone which module should i use for this purpose.

Comment: google "arduino bluetooth sound module"

Comment: An ESP32 could to that